# First occurrence of regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text string for a  answer test:

```
a) Berlin (Alemania).  b) Francia.   c) Reino Unido.
```

I'm using  the

```
^.*([aA]\s*\))(.*)([bB]\s*\))(.*)([cC]\s*\))(.*)
```

for grouping by answer and content of the answer, eg:

> Group(1): a)
>
> Group(2): Berlin (Alemania)
>
> Group(3): b)
>
> Group(4): Francia
>
> Group(5): c)
>
> Group(6): Reino Unido

what I get is:

> Group(1): a)
>
> Group(2): .
>
> Group(3): b)
>
> Group(4): Francia
>
> Group(5): c)
>
> Group(6): Reino Unido

the problem is with the Group(2), I get just the dot "."
The regular expression doesn't care about the first "a)"

Comment: The first `a)` is from `(Alemania)`. Is the input you have the whole input? Or is there anything before the first choice?

Comment: sometimes could be same blank spaces

Comment: Thanks, it was perfect, but if I put a blank at the starting of the string it doesn't work ("  a) Berlin (Alemania).  b) The same as c)   c) Reino Unido.) Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
^([aA]\s*\))(.*)([bB]\s*\))(.*)([cC]\s*\))(.*)
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/RKHBLWjZgW)

**Output :**

[image]